# What are the criteria for "community bumping"?

Tags: discussion

I think it's the third time around I see [the same question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90200/make-an-area-transparent-through-all-the-layers-in-gimp) necro-bumped by "Community"?

There are already three answers...

Where is that "dead parrot" icon when we need it?

Answer (score 4):

> [P]osts eligible for bumping are those scoring >= 0 that have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one non-deleted answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be deleted or closed).

(from [*Community ♦ seems to be bumping new questions more frequently than usual*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/244929))

You may also find [*Who is the "Community" User?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/244929) useful reading.

Comment: I see. No "stop" criteria in this.

Comment: @xenoid: *No "stop" criteria in this.* – All it takes is that one of the answers is upvoted or accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The post notice for Community bumped questions says:

> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

So the point of bumping the question is to *review answers* on the question, not to get attention for the question itself. Only non-negative scoring questions with 0 scored answers will be bumped.

So.... vote on the answers and it shall cease to be bumped.

Comment: I have answered it. I can't upvote my answer and won't upvote others since they are obviously inferior :)